# 1>/dev/null and >/dev/null and &>/dev/null

Tags: bash, redirect

```
i=5
expr $i + 6 1>/dev/null
```

Redirect stdout to /dev/null.
How about

```
expr $i + 6 >/dev/null
```

What is the difference between `expr $i + 6 1>/dev/null` and `expr $i + 6 >/dev/null`?

Someone writes

```
expr $i + 6 &>/dev/null
```

And what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`command >/dev/null` is a shorthand for `command 1>/dev/null`, it redirects stdout to `/dev/null`.

`command &>/dev/null` is a shorthand for `command 1>/dev/null 2>&1`, it redirects both stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.